# Is IISReset /noforce just as kind as "net stop w3svc, IISAdmin"?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

My organization has a framework app that runs on a number of client servers, where remote clients connect via HTTP. The server is a Server 2008 r2, usually a VM. Some of these boxes are also acting as a DB server, SMTP server, or AD server.

Every once in a while, background processes within this framework will hang. An IISReset /noforce does the trick, and setting it up as a weekly scheduled task has meant we haven't seen the issue in a couple months.

Today, however, I read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sudeepg/archive/2009/02/14/windows-2008-and-iisreset-exe.aspx) and [here](http://jnjnboo.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/do-not-use-iisreset-in-windows-2008-alternatives-listed/) that this isn't a good practice, that there may be non-HTTP processes in the app pool I'm restarting which will be interrupted. One article recommends executing a bat file, which would make the scheduled task a pretty simple affair.

I know that adding the /noforce parm to IISReset tells it to wait for the current threads to exit before it restarts, which seems like it would be pretty important. Will the following bat let the current threads finish before stopping? Does it even matter?

```
@echo off
net stop w3svc
net stop IISAdmin
net start IISAdmin
net start w3svc
@echo on
```

Comment: Your `here` and `here` links are non-existent.

Comment: @TheCleaner, I knew I'd forget that before posting. They're up now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can see is that `IISreset /noforce` will wait up to 1 minute for all IIS services to restart while IIS Manager will wait up to 5 minutes.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758159(v=ws.10).aspx